# NodeJS: Making routing level variables in expressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to express. I am confused on how can I set a variable in a helper function and later use that within the app.get() function.

```
var authenticate = (req,res,next) => {

// I need to set a user specific variable here
next();

}

app.use(authenticate);

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{

// I need to access the variable here.

});
```

Please note that the variable value can vary between different browser calls. So the variable should have a scope just for the call. I am confused on how to set it? Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best would be to add it to the req scope, here you have some documentation about it http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req

```
var authenticate = (req,res,next) => {

    req.authenticatedUser = {name: 'a'}
    next();

}

app.use(authenticate);

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{

    console.log(req.authenticatedUser);

});
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess this was what I was looking for. But can I add any number of such variables like req.<anything> or should I use something like req.locals.<anything>?

Comment: Also I hope this has scope ONLY for that particular request..right?

Comment: Sure, it's request based, and OFC that request is only present on that single call. Also it can be used as `req.<anything>` but keep in mind to not overwrite other values that could have valuable information (see the request docs)

Comment: thanks! this helps! again, I am free to use an object here..right? I can still use req.locals.<anything>..right?